# Migrate RealmSwift data to Core Data, removing RealmSwift dependency?

Tags: swift, core-data, realm

I am using RealmSwift to store data in my production app, but the next update will use Core Data + CloudKit to handle data storage and iCloud sync. I have the Core Data stack set up, and I could easily migrate the Realm data to Core Data but I don't want to just have the Realm framework hanging on as a dependency when I don't need it anymore. Is there a way to migrate the data after removing Realm from my app? I know the default.realm file would still be there but I have no idea how I'd parse it without Realm.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to migrate realm db after you have removed the dependency to it then you will have to write your own implementation for that. An implementation you will have a dependency to even though it is not used anymore. I am not sure this would be an improvement

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of reading your realm data into Realm objects, crafting new objects for the Core Data graph and storing them? Once you're stored the data in CD there would be no need for the Realm framework - what's stopping you from removing it? We went the other way a couple of years ago, and once we implemented Realm, we removed all references to CD. (we wanted multi-user, which prompted our move)

Comment: @Jay the problem is the app is in production. Transferring data into CD is super simple, but I can't delete the framework because then I can't transfer the data. I also can't just transfer the data and then delete the Realm framework after a couple months because you never know if someone hasn't updated and would lose all their data.

Comment: On your next app release with removed Realm, why not also release a Migration Assistant app the user runs to migrate their data from the 'old format' to the 'new format', letting the user know the old app data will be sunsetted at the end of the year. That's pretty painless.

Comment: @Miles - How did you approach the migration process, would you mind sharing your final process? - I'm currently trying to move from Realm to Core Data for the same reason as you.

Comment: @Jay - Would you mind elaborating a little more on your last comment? Are you suggesting to basically release two different apps to the AppStore, a brand new one with no `Realm` in it and which will be the master/future app and a temporary app just to migrate the data from the old app that uses `Realm` to the new one?

Comment: @Jay (2)- If my last statement is true, the brand new app will have to have a totally different name and the temporary Migration Assistant app will have to have the same name as the existing app but where would you transfer the data to? Also, does that mean that existing users will have to stop using the existing and start using the new one with different name after they migrate their data? Thanks.

Comment: @fs_tigre I ended up keeping the Realm framework in the app (along with the migration code of course) for a few months, and then when I was doing some cleanup of the code I decided to get rid of it. But... then I got emails of people complaining they updated (clearly they skipped 8+ updates) and lost all their data. So I decided to just add Realm back to the project just for migration. A bit annoying but better than users losing their data. Basically you can never assume a user will update at all, and when they do update they can skip any number of important updates.

Comment: @fs_tigre I wouldn't go the "migration assistant" app route, I believe that would be more for a desktop that can bypass the app store. Either way not very user friendly.

Comment: @fs_tigre The goal was to release an app with no dependency on Realm. One option is to release a migration tool that helps migrate their data from the "old" to the "new". The old app would continue to work with the old data, and the new app will use the migrated data. For example - release a version of the app that has a 'migrate' button which upon being done, would then allow the next version of the app (which is Realm-less) to use the new data.

Comment: @Miles - thanks a lot for sharing your experience, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Jay - thank you for the clarification. One more thing to fully understand your thought. Where would you save the data, to the Files folder and then read it from there? Is that even possible. Thanks

Comment: @fs_tigre The options are limitless; the files could be saved/exported as say a flat file and then imported into CD. Or: the data could be pushed up to a server where the data is massaged into another format. Or, it could be a live thing where in verison A of the app, the data is read and then pushed to CD and then when the user updates to verison B (the realmless version) it would use the data from CD. Or... many other paths for migrating that data.